Time minus time geting only hours, not days
having some kind of problem and dont know how to fix it, ok imagine
my code:
$row2['from'] = 2024-04-03 09:00:00
$row2['till'] = 2024-04-04 21:00:00

$datetime= strtotime($row2['from']) - strtotime($row2['till']);

echo gmdate("H:i", $datetime);

And my echo is 12:00, i know that its counting only hours, but maybe someone has solution how to make that it looked like 1 day, 12:00 hours.
Didnt have any ideas

You might want to convert them to DateTime instances and use DateInterval instead

In PHP you can use date_diff() function on DateTime objects.
$datetime1 = date_create('2024-04-03 09:00:00');
$datetime2 = date_create('2024-04-04 21:00:00');

$diff = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo $diff->format('%y years %m months %d days %h hours');


okay it workts, thank you! i have one more question. using date_diff how to make if there was +1 day wrote 1 day 12 hours, but if there was no +1 day just the time ?

Function date_diff returns DateInterval object, which has own properties and functions. You can just access days by writing $diff->d and create some logic using this and other properties - you can find more about DateInterval class in PHP documentation. (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)
